# Abort systemd target

Tags: systemd, services

The reason is there is an application that is running full screen. When system is about to suspend due to inactivity, first I want to show a count down dialog so if the user is present can abort it if he/she want to. I'm trying to show a dialog on a application before suspend target on the system is triggered (i.e. when we press suspend button) first a dialog is appeared on my application and if user didn't cancel it, system will suspend. I want to create a service that runs before the suspend.target and if failed (return code 1) suspend does not happen. Is it possible to abort a target this way?

Comment: so are you asking about suspend when the button is pressed, or about suspend when the system is inactive?

Comment: @user1686 about the suspend when the system is inactivate. I want to show a dialog box to confirm the suspend.

Comment: In case I forget to post a full answer, a probably better mechanism would be to use inhibitors, not to hook into the target.